# Javascript/jQuery add class on click not working on circle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Through the years I already found a lot of answers over here, but now I'm really stuck on something and writing my first posted question ever!

I am making a website with some graphs. The background of the graph is an image showing the x and y-axis. I am drawing all the dots using Javascript and positioning them based on data out of a .txt-file. That is all working (yay!), but... here's my problem:

I've got 15 people who answered in 7 graphs. When you click on a dot from person1 in graph1, I want this dot and all the dots from this person in the other graphs to become bigger. All the dots have 2 classes: .circle and .circle[number] (each circle[number] appears in every graph, so the [number] is the person ID). So I though adding the class .big to .circle1 when clicked would do the trick, but I for some reason the class is never added.

I tried all my stuff that usually works, also tried a lot of answers I found over here and when I try this on for instance the title of my page it is working. So I have a feeling the problem lies with the dots... I already made sure that the dots are above the image, so that is not the problem. And when I style the dot with an hover it does know on which one I'm hovering and makes it bigger. Also tried adding some HTML in the divs, but still not working.

I'm drawing the dots using Javascript in HTML like this:

```
<div class="circle circle0" style="position: absolute; left: 275.988px; top: 165.559px;"></div>
<div class="circle circle1" style="position: absolute; left: 231.204px; top: 141.898px;"></div>
<div class="circle circle2" style="position: absolute; left: 228.308px; top: 138.01px;"></div>
etc... (in every graph, so 7 times but every time different positions based on the data)

.circle {
   border-width: 2px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 10px; 
   height: 10px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

An example of what is not working (only on the dots, when using a title it is working):

```
$(".circle").on("click",function(){
    $(".circle").addClass("big");
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is not working and how it can work?
Thanks!

ANSWER: There was nothing wrong with the code, I just had to move my code a level higher (stupid! Sometimes it's so simple..)

Comment: Just to verify you want to add the class "big" to all of the circles when one of them is clicked ?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7sm45625/ so there must be something else going on

Comment: Sometimes I'm so stupid. I just had to move my block of code one layer up! I've been staring at this problem for so long. Too long, I guess ;) (it's already after midnight over here) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "big" class in your CSS, so that might be one reason it's not working.  Here's an example of it working with your code and the class added:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".circle0").on("click",function(){
      $(".circle0").toggleClass("big");
   });
   $(".circle1").on("click",function(){
      $(".circle1").toggleClass("big");
   });
   $(".circle2").on("click",function(){
      $(".circle2").toggleClass("big");
   });
});
```

```css
.circle {
   border-width: 2px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 10px; 
   height: 10px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   z-index: 999;
}

.big {
   width: 15px; 
   height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle circle0" style="position: absolute; left: 275.988px; top: 165.559px;"></div>
<div class="circle circle1" style="position: absolute; left: 231.204px; top: 141.898px;"></div>
<div class="circle circle2" style="position: absolute; left: 228.308px; top: 138.01px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil, it turned out to be a level issue. Just had to move that block of code one level up, now it's working like a charm :)